# include path is not working when referencing another file

Tags: php

I'm having problem with **include()** and **require_once()** this is what I have on my script on report-publisher file that resides here :

C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports\report-publishers.php

now i want to include this file:

```
<?php include("images/report-publisher-completed.php");?>
```

and the directory of that script is here:

C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports\images\report-publisher-completed.php

it works the problem is in this report-publisher-completed.php i have the following:

`require_once("../../includes/database.php");`

here is the location of that file: C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\includes\database.php

so when i run the code I get the following error:

> ( ! ) Warning: require_once(../../includes/database.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports\images\report-publisher-completed.php
>   on line 3
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../../includes/database.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports\images\report-publisher-completed.php
>   on line 3

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer way to include a file is to use a relative path from the current script, using the constant `__dir__`, like this :

```
include __dir__ . '/includes/database.php';
```

So, for your case, probably :

```
include __dir__ . '/../../includes/database.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../includes/database.php');
```

Comment: still an error

 ( ! ) Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports/includes/database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklists\reports\images\report-publisher-completed.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/database.php";
```

Instead of

```
require_once("../../includes/database.php");
```